# Make a if else return in one line

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes 4 parameters.

```
function fillTheText (selector, arrText, arrEl, j) {
  if (j >= 0) {
    return document.querySelector(selector + [j]).innerHTML = arrText[arrEl][j];
  } else {
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = arrText[arrEl];
  }
}
```

The above function is invoked three times

```
function startQuiz (question) {
  fillTheText('#question', question[i], 'text');
  for (let j = 0; j < question[i].choices.length; j++) {
    fillTheText('#choice', question[i], 'choices', j)
  }
}
```

I want to make changes so that `fillTheText` returns a single line but have no idea how can I make `[j]` optional. I tried conditional (ternary) operators but did not succeed.

Comment: No, just use the if else syntax. Ternary operator makes the reader confused for complex situations.

Comment: what code did you try ?

Comment: basically above code works, but I don't think it follows DRY methodology, so  I played with it for hours, and all solutions were bad.

Comment: @Vlad check the answer and let me know

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but you just want the `[j]` optional in the first function right? So mantain the `if else` and just give a default value to `[j]` at the begining of your function `function fillTheText (selector, arrText, arrEl, j = -1)`, that way when you don't pass the `[j]` on the function, it will asign `j = -1` and it will run the else part of the statement

Comment: Why `selector + [j]` with the square brackets? That creates an Array, puts `j` in it, then converts it to a string, which ends up the same as `selector + j`.

Answer (score 4):

Not one line, but still an improvement, I think.

```
function fillTheText (selector, arrText, arrEl, j) {
  var selector = j >= 0 ? selector + [j] : selector;
  var value = j >= 0 ? arrText[arrEl][j] : arrText[arrEl];

  document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value;
}
```

Or, perhaps, this

```
function fillTheText (selector, arrText, arrEl, j) {
  var value = arrText[arrEl];

  if (j >= 0) {
    selector = selector + [j];
    value = value[j];
  }

  document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139700/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-tulentsev-make-a-if-else-return-in-one-line).

Answer (score 3):

Use `ternary operator`

the line `j>=0` means j's value is 0 or greater.

### The Ternary operator

syntax : `condition?true:false`

If the condition is true, the part after `?` will execute else the part after `:` will execute

```
function fillTheText (selector, arrText, arrEl, j) {
    return (typeof j==typeof 123 && j>=0) ? document.querySelector(selector + [j]).innerHTML = arrText[arrEl][j] : document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = arrText[arrEl];
 }
```

Comment: Works, thanks a lot, will set as a answer after 8 minutes

Comment: Please do not use html/js/css snippets for something that is not actually an immediately runnable piece of code (such as this one).

Comment: `j && j >= 0` is odd for a condition because if `j` is `0`, it will never make it to the `j >= 0` part, so you'll never actually get the first expression when `j == 0`.

Comment: @Vlad: Seriously, don't use code like this. Why are you so concerned about having this on one line? The readability of this solution is abysmal.

Comment: @squint thanks. I didn't aware of the 0. thanks for spotting. updated.

Comment: `j >= 0` will return an error, if `undefined`. Please refer to my answer for reference.

Comment: @Daerik: Error messages are good. They exist to tell you that something is wrong in your program. If you're going to hide this error, why not hide them all by wrapping your whole program in a try/catch with no error handling?

Comment: @squint I personally know that Firefox will stop compiling JavaScript if it encounters an error, making any functionality downward useless. You do not want errors in your Javascript. That is bad programming.

Comment: @Daerik: It doesn't stop compiling. That would be a runtime error. It just empties the call stack unless there's a `try/catch` somewhere. If you really don't want errors in your program, then you need to *allow* error messages, otherwise you're letting them continue to exist.

Comment: @squint The OP is intentionally calling the function with `j` being optional. `fillTheText('#question', question[i], 'text');` Does not pass `j`.

Comment: @Daerik: Yes, I know. That changes nothing I've written.